# When is a new PHP-CGI process created?

Tags: php, wordpress, fastcgi

[image]

My production server has been having a OOM issue. Upon investigating I find that a major memory eater is PHP-CGI processes. Each of my website, be it Joomla or Wordpress, is having 3 - 6 PHP-CGI processes and each of the processes is taking around 80MB memory.

So I created a brand new test server and transferred one of the simplest Wordpress sites over. This site has only a few common plugins like Astra and Elementor and no modification at all, besides I haven't pointed the A record to the new server, meaning there won't be any visitors even spiders. And I got the screenshot above. Even without any visitor, this new site(kcmc) has created 3 php-cgi processes. Meanwhile, I have checked another server of mine which hosts only 1 production Joomla site. On this server the website only creates 1 php-cgi process.

So this raises my question:

When and why is a php-cgi process created?

**Update**
Here is my Apache server's setting:

```
<Directory /home/kcmc/public_html>
    Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.4
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php8.1
    FCGIWrapper /home/kcmc/fcgi-bin/php8.1.fcgi .php
    FCGIWrapper /home/kcmc/fcgi-bin/php7.4.fcgi .php7.4
    FCGIWrapper /home/kcmc/fcgi-bin/php8.1.fcgi .php8.1
</Directory>
<Directory /home/kcmc/cgi-bin>
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.kcmc.com
RewriteRule ^(?!/.well-known)(.*) https://kcmc.com:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.kcmc.com
RewriteRule ^(?!/.well-known)(.*) https://kcmc.com:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php7.4
RemoveHandler .php8.1
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/kcmc/ssl.cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/kcmc/ssl.key
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
IPCCommTimeout 31
```

Comment: Depends on your httpd's settings, eg: nginx or apache.

Comment: @Sammitch I've updated the question posting .conf file